# MultiForm Updateview Django

Tags: django, forms

Using django-betterforms.MultiForm with Django 1.8, I have no problem with CreateView.
 But I get this error when using UpdateView :
*'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'*
from python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in model_to_dict, line

```
 opts = instance._meta
```

from /python3.4/site-packages/betterforms/multiform.py in __init__

```
self.forms[key] = form_class(*fargs, **fkwargs)
```

Here are my models :

```
    class Salle(models.Model):
        nom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        adresse_d_attache = models.ForeignKey(Adresse, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    class Adresse(models.Model):
        numero_voie_nomvoie = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Here are the forms and the multiform :

```
    class SalleForm_avec_objet_adresse(MultiForm):
        form_classes = OrderedDict((
            ('salle', SalleForm_sans_objet_adresse),
            ('adresse', Adresseform),
        ))

    class SalleForm_sans_objet_adresse(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Salle

    class Adresseform(ModelForm):
        ville_selection = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'ville_selection', 'placeholder': 'Choix d\'une ville'}))
        class Meta:
            model = Adresse
```

Here's the updateview :

```
class Salle_avec_objet_adresse_updateview(UpdateView):
    model = Salle
    form_class = SalleForm_avec_objet_adresse
    template_name = 'Impro_Annuaire_P3_D17/salle_createview.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(Salle_avec_objet_adresse_updateview, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(instance={
            'salle': self.object,
            'adresse': self.object.adresse_d_attache,
        })
        return kwargs
```

This error comes from the kwargs.update part. Removing it causes the multiform to appear in my template with salle being the only filled part.
Although it looks to me pretty much like [in the doc](http://django-betterforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/multiform.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your:

```
class SalleForm_avec_objet_adresse(MultiForm):
        form_classes = OrderedDict((
            ('salle', SalleForm_sans_objet_adresse),
            ('adresse', Adresseform),
        ))
```

should inherit after MultiModelForm instead of MultiForm.

http://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html